# Why does Alloy not find a counter-example for a simple tree structure?

Tags: alloy

Here is a minimized Alloy model I tested with Alloy 6.1.0 on macOS:

```
sig Root {}

sig NonRoot {
  root : one Root,
  parent : lone NonRoot
}

fact acyclic {
  no i : NonRoot | i in i.^parent
}

fact root_consistent_with_ancestors {
  all i : NonRoot
  | i.root = i.^parent.root
}

assert no_ancestry {
  no disj nr1, nr2 : NonRoot
  | nr1.parent = nr2
}

check no_ancestry for 6
```

It seems like Alloy should be able to find a small counter example to this with the following structure:

- 1 root node R
- 1 non-root node N1 with `root = { R }` and `parent = none`
- 1 non-root node N2 with `root = { R }` and `parent = { N1 }`.

Am I misunderstanding something or is this an Alloy bug?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this `fact` is too constraining:

```
fact root_consistent_with_ancestors {
  all i : NonRoot
  | i.root = i.^parent.root
}
```

For the case of the first child of the root which doesn't have a parent, `i.^parent.root` is the empty set. However, `i.root` is a singleton set.

As a consequence, Alloy will not generate any `NonRoot` elements at all.

This can be tested by removing the `check` and generating examples using:

```
pred example {}
run example for 3
```

You'll see that only `Root` nodes are being generated.

One way to fix the model is to use `i.parent = none or i.root = i.^parent.root`. That gives the desired result.

[image: Alloy counter-example showing tree ancestry]